# Theano function not working on a simple, 4-value array

Tags: python, arrays, theano, brackets, square-bracket

I was working through the theano documentation/tutorial, and the very first example was this:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> import theano.tensor as T
>>> from theano import function
>>> x = T.dscalar('x')
>>> y = T.dscalar('y')
>>> z = x + y
>>> f = function([x, y], z)
```

This seemed simple enough, and so I wrote my own program that expanded on it:

```
import numpy as np
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import function

x = T.dscalar('x')
y = T.dscalar('y')

z = x + y
f = function([x, y], z)


print f(2, 3)
print np.allclose(f(16.3, 12.1), 28.4) 
print ""

r  = (2, 3), (2, 2), (2, 1), (2, 0)

for i in r:
    print i
    print f(i)
```

And for some reason, it won't iterate:

```
5.0
True

(2, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TheanoBase2.py", line 20, in <module>
    print f(i)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 786, in __call__
    allow_downcast=s.allow_downcast)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/type.py", line 177, in filter
    data.shape))
TypeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name "TheanoBase2.py:9"  at index 0(0-based)', 'Wrong number of dimensions: expected 0, got 1 with shape (2,).')
```

Why does `print f(2, 3)` work and `print f(i)` not work, when they're the exact same expression. I tried replacing/enclosing the brackets with square brackets, and the result was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function f` take two scalars as input and return their sum, each element of `r` i.e (x, y) is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) not a scalar. This should work:

```
import numpy as np
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import function

x = T.dscalar('x')
y = T.dscalar('y')

z = x + y
f = function([x, y], z)

print f(2, 3)
print np.allclose(f(16.3, 12.1), 28.4) 
print ""

r  = (2, 3), (2, 2), (2, 1), (2, 0)

for i in r:
    print i
    print f(i[0], i[1])
```

Comment: Thank you, so much. I had absolutely no idea what was happening.

Comment: But just for future reference,  how would I make Theano accept a tuple?

Comment: Glad it helped.
Only [these types](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#all-fully-typed-constructors) are supported, you cannot use tuple directly, if it's a single tuple then cast it to vector, for list of tuples you can use matrix.
`import numpy as np`
`x_=(2,3)`
`x = np.asarray(a, dtype='int32')`